# Integrate a function that doesn't directly operate element-wise

Tags: matlab, math, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I'm working on a Matlab script that involves fourth order tensors calculations volume integrals. Let H(r,theta,phi) be the function I want to integrate. Assume that H cannot be obtained by simple operations on r, theta and phi.

My problem is that in Matlab as in any other code I know :

```
All input functions must accept arrays and operate elementwise. The function FUN(X,Y,Z)
must accept arrays X, Y, Z of the same size and return an array of corresponding values.
```

This is from the implementation of the [integral3 function](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral3.html) from Matlab.

If I try with this simple function :

```
fun = @(X,Y,Z) X.*Y.*Z
```

There is no problem at all and if I integrate it over [0,1] x [0,1] x [0,1], I get the right result :

```
integral3(fun,0,1,0,1,0,1)
```

returns 0.125 which is correct.

The problem is that as I said, I can't perform simple calculations with the vectors to obtain H and I am forced to do things more or less this way :

```
function [result] = fun(x,y,z)
    sz = length(x);
    result  = zeros(1,sz);
    for i=1:sz
        result(i) = x(i)*y(i)*z(i);
    end
end
```

This function works on its own and returns exactly the same results as the other one I introduced earlier. However, when I try to use integral3  I get this error :

```
Error using integral2Calc>integral2t/tensor (line 241)
Integrand output size does not match the input size
```

But it can clearly be seen from the definition of my function that I specifically made it the size of the input.

I don't understand what's wrong and I'm not sure I have any other solution to compute this function than using this kind of syntax.

Thanks a lot for your time and help :)

Comment: Nothing to add to the answer of @drhagen but I just want to thank you for this beautifully written question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you are building an array with the correct length but the wrong size. It is a subtle difference in Matlab. I'm guessing that `integral3` is passing in a column vector, but your function always returns a row vector. The column and row vectors have the same "length" `sz`, but different "sizes": the column vector is `[sz,1]` and the row vector is `[1,sz]`. The code below does what you want because it uses `size` to ensure that all the dimensions of the output match the input and `numel` to loop over the individual elements:

```
function result = fun(x,y,z)
    sz = size(x);
    result = zeros(sz);
    for i = 1:numel(x)
        result(i) = x(i)*y(i)*z(i);
    end
end
```

A good rule-of-thumb is to only use `size` and `numel` and never use `length`, which is a contender for worst function in Matlab.

Comment: @drhagen It works when I use `size` and a double loop over `size(1)` and `size(2)` just in case the function `integral3` uses an array instead of a column or a row vector, thank you ! 

Also, thank you for the length advice!

Comment: @JeremyDiallo Actually, due to linear indexing, my version will work if supplied with an array, even if its an array that's 2D, 3D, 4D, etc.

Comment: @drhagen Wow I didn't know about automatic linear indexing in matlab, I'd better look it up. Thanks for your help !